# need to search lines containing specific string pattern

Tags: shell, search, if-statement, awk

I am checking if the current line read by awk contains some strings for which I am using:

```
if (/.*abc.*lab.*/)
 {
 }
```

but if the string in the line is e.g.

```
[abc ls:lab=123 ....]..
```

then the string is searched correctly, but if the line contains e.g.

```
[abc ls:key=xyz xyz. ls:lab=123 ...]..
```

then the line is not searched even though it matches `.*abc.*lab.*`

Can someone please correct me if I am doing some mistake while searching?

Comment: Could you try to clarify what you mean by "if the string in the line is e.g. ".." then the string is searched correctly, but if the line contains e.g. ".." then the line is not searched even though it matches .*abc.lab."?

Comment: What shell is this? It doesn't match any shell syntax I've ever seen...

Comment: What is the input field separator (`FS`) you've specified?

Comment: @michaelb958: the code is a fragment of `awk` code; the data lines are just data lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
awk '/abc.*lab/ { print $0 }'
```

The pattern is matched against `$0`, the whole line.  However, what you wrote should also work if written as:

```
awk '{if (/.*abc.*lab.*/) print $0}'
```

or with a simpler regex:

```
awk '{if (/abc.*lab/) print $0}'
```

If you don't have the `if` inside the `{ ... }`, then you've got syntactic problems with `awk`.

Given a data file like this:

```
[abc ls:lab=123 ....]..
then the string is searched correctly, but if the line contains e.g.

[abc ls:key=xyz xyz. ls:lab=123 ...]..
```

the scripts above all produce:

```
[abc ls:lab=123 ....]..
[abc ls:key=xyz xyz. ls:lab=123 ...]..
```